# WPF Datagrid Selected Row Color and Centered Text

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I have a simple `DataGrid` where I want to Style the selected row and center the text. I have tried the following and it does not work:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Why will the above not work together? If I remove the trigger, it will center but the color I want will not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add *`Grid`* to the ControlTemplate of `DataGridCell` style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```